# Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on writing a parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`: Java heap space error. I reduced my code down to just three steps. Open a parquet file, and then write it, and I get this error. My machine has 128 GB of RAM, tbs of HD. I have tried the below steps for spark-shell, pyspark, and also python code

Here is what I did

1. open spark-shell (default settings no additional params)
2. val asd = sqlContext.read.parquet("/spark/data/xxx/yyy")
3. asd.registerTempTable("yyy")
4. asd.write.parquet("data/test")

and I get the following error

```
5/09/21 19:03:29 INFO CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.gz] 
15/09/21 19:03:29 INFO CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.gz] 
15/09/21 19:03:29 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting task. 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:30 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting task. 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:29 INFO CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.gz] 
15/09/21 19:03:29 INFO ParquetOutputFormat: Validation is off 
15/09/21 19:03:31 INFO ParquetOutputFormat: Writer version is: PARQUET_1_0 
15/09/21 19:03:31 ERROR DefaultWriterContainer: Task attempt attempt_201509211903_0009_m_000004_0 aborted. 
15/09/21 19:03:31 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 293) 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows. 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$sources$InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$writeRows$1(commands.scala:191) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(commands.scala:160) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(commands.scala:160) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:31 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting task. 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:31 ERROR DefaultWriterContainer: Task attempt attempt_201509211903_0009_m_000002_0 aborted. 
15/09/21 19:03:31 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 291) 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows. 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$sources$InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$writeRows$1(commands.scala:191) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(commands.scala:160) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(commands.scala:160) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:31 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting task. 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:31 INFO CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.gz] 
15/09/21 19:03:32 ERROR DefaultWriterContainer: Task attempt attempt_201509211903_0009_m_000003_0 aborted. 
15/09/21 19:03:32 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 292) 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows. 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$sources$InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$writeRows$1(commands.scala:191) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(commands.scala:160) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(commands.scala:160) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:32 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting task. 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:32 ERROR DefaultWriterContainer: Task attempt attempt_201509211903_0009_m_000006_0 aborted. 
15/09/21 19:03:32 INFO CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.gz] 
15/09/21 19:03:32 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting task. 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:33 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 6.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 295) 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows. 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$sources$InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$writeRows$1(commands.scala:191) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(commands.scala:160) 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(commands.scala:160) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63) 
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70) 
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:33 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting task. 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:33 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting task. 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
15/09/21 19:03:33 ERROR DefaultWriterContainer: Task attempt attempt_201509211903_0009_m_000008_0 aborted. 
15/09/21 19:03:33 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 8.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 297) 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
```

Comment: Why do you try registerTempTable("yyy") if you are not using this table later? Does the code work without this step?

Comment: You can always throw memory at it, could you try `spark-shell --driver-memory Xg --executor-memory Xg`? Where `X` is around 0.75 of the system memory.

Comment: @Abhi - Did you ever find an answer to this? I've run into something similar and increasing my driver-memory did not help.